# How to apply a custom ordering to a multi index column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multi index (column) data frame similar to the following:

```
my_frame = pd.DataFrame(data={'a':[1,2,3,4],'b':[5,6,7,8],'c':[9,10,11,12], 'd':[13,14,15,16],
                              'subcolumn_1':['A1','A1','A2','A2'],
                              'subcolumn_2':['B1','B2','B1','B2']})
my_frame.set_index(keys=['subcolumn_1','subcolumn_2'], inplace=True)
my_frame = my_frame.transpose()


subcolumn_1 A1  A2
subcolumn_2 B1  B2  B1  B2
a   1   2   3   4
b   5   6   7   8
c   9   10  11  12
d   13  14  15  16
```

I would like to sort `subcolumn_2` but not alphanumerically, but rather with a custom list, e.g like the following pseudo-code.

```
my_frame.sort_subcolumn_2(neworder=["B2","B1"])

subcolumn_1 A1  A2
subcolumn_2 B2  B1  B2  B1
a   2   1   4   3
b   6   5   8   7
c   10  9   12  11
d   14  13  16  15
```

EDIT: My use case requires the sorting to be done after the new indexes
have been set. The current solutions require I sort prior to setting
the indexes

Comment: can you please elaborate on why only `b` and `c` were reordered but `subcolumn_1` and `a` weren't?

Comment: Made an edit to hopefully clarify your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to cast subcolumn_2 into ordered categorical,

```
from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype

cat_type = CategoricalDtype(categories=['B2','B1','B3'], ordered=True)

my_frame['subcolumn_2'] = my_frame['subcolumn_2'].astype(cat_type)
```

Try

```
my_frame.sort_values(by=['subcolumn_2'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd maybe try and use `np.argsort` to get the new desired order of rows,

then use `.iloc` to order by it before transposing.

try this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

my_frame = pd.DataFrame(data={'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [7, 8, 9], 'c': [4, 5, 6],
                              'subcolumn_1': ['A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
                              'subcolumn_2': ['B1', 'B2', 'B3']})

neworder = ["B2", "B1", "B3"]
print(my_frame.iloc[np.argsort(neworder)].set_index(keys=['subcolumn_1', 'subcolumn_2']).transpose())
```

Output:

```
subcolumn_1 A2 A1 A3
subcolumn_2 B2 B1 B3
a            2  1  3
b            8  7  9
c            5  4  6
```